# Petersen graph edge chromatic number

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, problem-solving, coloring

Hi I keep on getting 3 for the edge chromatic number of the Petersen graph. But the Petersen graph has edge chromatic number of 4 and I don’t know how to do that. Can someone please show this by proving this.

Comment: What do you mean, you "got $3$" for the edge chromatic number? Does that mean you found a proper edge coloring with $3$ colors? If you did that, then you proved that the edge chromatic number is no greater than $3$. How else would you "get $3$"?

Answer (score -1):

Every cubic bridgeless graph has a perfect matching, hence we can find a perfect matching for the peterson graph and color the matched edges in one color. You can check that n o matter which perfect matching you choose to remove, After you remove the matched edges, you get two disjoint cycles on 5 vertices each. We know an odd cycle needs 3 colors to properly color the edges. Hence we can color the peterson graph using at most 4 colors and not less. So it's edge chromatic number is 4. I hope I did it right.

Comment: You have proved that the Petersen graph has a proper edge coloring with $4$ colors, but you have not proved that it has no proper edge coloring with $3$ colors. There is a perfect matching, but the edges of that perfect matching do not all have to get the same color.

Comment: Your argument seems to apply just as well to the [pentagonal prismgraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_prism) which has edge chromatic number $3$.